# Using a pandas dataframe to compare marketing data with the same data a certain time ago (one week, one year)

Tags: python

I am tasked at work to build a report that shows marketing data on campaign level segmented by days. The main challenge is to fulfill the requirement of comparing different data to the same data a week ago. Unfortunately, Excel is not an option (here, the =CALCULATE formula would do the trick in Power Pivot).

I decided to use Google Sheets, with at table structured like this:

```
Day        | Account | Campaign | Cost
2020-03-23 | Acc1    | Camp1    | 12.3
2020-03-22 | Acc1    | Camp2    | 15.3
```

Now, I added a column 'Cost 1w' that should get the the cost form the same campaign in the same account one week ago. This data then is used in a Pivot to analyse it. The formula for this is
`=SUMIFS($D:$D, $A:$A, $A2-7, $B:$B, $B2, $C:$C, $C2)`

As this calculation makes Sheets very slow, and I want to automate the way i import the data, I started to use Python to get the data from an API to a Pandas dataframe and write it into the sheet. I only have no idea about how to calculate the 'Cost 1w' column in the dataframe, even though I tried the solutions I found online. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please provide enough sample data to actually test against, and your expected output, to make a [mcve]. See [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: please attach code whatever you have tried so far